# ©Law of True Love

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, situation

> Katy flipped again and denied payment after the police left.
>
> Professor: "Hey! Please provide your parent’s number."
>
> Katy: "Sorry I flipped! Anyways I live with my aunt! Please dial 82244444355"
>
> Professor: "Don't lie. You've changed the order!"
>
> Katy: "Haven't I said. To the point!!"
>
> Professor: "You will go to such lengths to get what you want, wont you"
>
> Katy: "Oh god! Your car dashes, and dots get connected!!"

**What is the name of Katy's aunt?**

Comment: Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: If anyone is solving this and is stuck, please let me know where you are stuck so that I can help!

Comment: @thisIs4d Perhaps it would be helpful if you could give the length of Katy's aunt's name.

Comment: @TylerSelden Please let me know where are you stuck if possible. I can tell you whether the direction is wrong or not.

Comment: @TylerSelden Those were tge exactly things I did. Even if I try to extract a name somehow, I have no clue on what to do with that number.

Comment: rot13(V guvax gur ahzore jvyy or hfvat n cubar xrlcnq (frr uggcf://jjj.qpbqr.se/zhygvgnc-nop-pvcure), ohg gung tvirf GO[TUV]*QX, qrcraqvat ba ubj gubfr 4f ner qvivqrq, juvpu qbrfa'g znxr nal frafr ol vgfrys.)

Comment: @thisIs4d does the last sentence indicate that, (rot13) Vg unf gb qb jvgu zbefr pbqr (qbgf naq qnfurf) ?

Comment: That would also explain "length" and "to the point"

Comment: @WOWOW That would also explain the hint that was taken out. rot13(V jnf cynlvat nebhaq jvgu hfvat chapghngvba nf zbefr pbqr (urapr gur vapbeerpg chapghngvba va gur ynfg yvar sebz gur Cebsrffbe) ohg V guvax vg unf gb or zbqvsvrq va fbzr jnl (r.t. "syvccrq", "gb gur cbvag", "qbgf trg pbaarpgrq").)

Comment: @TylerSelden rot13 - Znlor punenpgref, gung vapyhqr n qbg yvxr "!" ohg ner abg n "." trg pbaarpgrq, be gur bccbfvgr. Cebonoyl fbzrguvat yvxr gung

Comment: @WOWOW Yes, the last sentence indicates rot13(zbefr pbqr vf vaibyirq)